# Display r Shiny actionButton Title in mouseover popup

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have done research on how to display `actionButton` title when `mouseover`. I understand javascript, but not sure how to fix this issue.

On `mouseover`, I want the `Title` of `Button` to be displayed not the html code itself.  I will appreciate any help or ideas to solve this. Below is POC code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  # create a summary table
    summary_iris <- group_by(iris, Species) %>%
      summarise(Count = n())

    summary_iris$Species <- levels(summary_iris$Species)

    shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, label, ...) {
      inputs <- character(len)

      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        label <- summary_iris$Species[i]
        inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i),label=label, ...))
      }
      inputs
    }

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT <- summary_iris %>%
        mutate(Species = shinyInput(actionButton,
                                    nrow(summary_iris), 'button_', label = Species, class="bttn-unite",
                                    onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)'))
      DT::datatable(DT, rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
                    options = list(rowCallback = JS(
                      "function(row, data) {",
                      "var full_text = data[0]",
                      "$('td:eq(0)', row).attr('title', full_text);",
                      "}")))
    })
  }
)
```

Again, thank you in advance for your help, pointers, or examples I missed during my research.

How do I make the button look like [Unite Button on this site](https://bttn.surge.sh/)? This is not important, but I was struggling with that too.

Comment: To have the `bttn-unite` class available, you can use the `shinyWidgets` package.

Comment: Thanks that did it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the text:

```
rowCallback = JS(
  "function(row, data) {",
  "  var r = />(.*)</;",
  "  var full_text = r.exec(data[0])[1]",
  "  $('td:eq(0)', row).attr('title', full_text);",
  "}")
```

Or you can turn the string into a HTML object with jQuery, and then extract the text:

```
rowCallback = JS(
  "function(row, data) {",
  "  var full_text = $(data[0]).text();",
  "  $('td:eq(0)', row).attr('title', full_text);",
  "}")
```

Comment: `@Stephane Laurent`, thank you so much. I like the second option, much easier to understand. This is exactly what I am looking for. Any recommendation on javascript resources that may help me be able to improve my javascript skills.  Again, thank you.